# Cant able to create multi tenant application using azure AAD Graph client

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I just try to create azure ad application from code using AAD graph client. For single tenant application it works fine and create application. But if i try to set AvailableToOtherTenants property to true it throws me error like "An Error Occured While Processing this request". Am I supposed to set any additional properties for multitenant application creation?

Comment: Are you able to set an application with the same "APP ID URI" to Multi-tenant? I am suspecting that your "APP ID URI" is not unique directories-wise.

Answer (score 0):

For a native application, the multi tenant is "by design" enabled.

For a web application, AvailableToOtherTenants should work

An other thing to notice : Be sure to precise "common" as your tenant id, not your tenant id name or guid

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that you want to check if that your application URI starts with the URI of your AAD, so if you have an AAD called Contoso, the URI of your application could be **https://contoso.onmicrosoft.com/my-application**.

While the application URI doesn't matter for single-tenant applications, for multi-tenant applications it has to start with the AAD tenant URI.

Comment: Yes URI matters for multi tenant application it needs starts with Tenant URI thanks for your help